# How to replace quotation marks in a file with sed?

Tags: sed

I have a file that contains multiple lines of xml. I would like to replace certain parts of the file. Some parts of the file contains quotation marks (`"`) which I would like to replace. I have been trying to *escape* the quotation mark with `\`, but I don't think this is working based on the result of my file.

Here is an example of one of my sed commands:

```
sed -e "s/\"text\"/'text'/ig" file.xml > temp.tmp
```

Is this how you escape quotation marks in a sed command or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your command looks right for replacing `"text"` with `'text'`. Of course it won't do anything to `"othertext"`. Show a few input lines, the corresponding undesired output, and explain what output you want instead.

Comment: So `\"` is the correct way of escaping quotation marks in sed command?

Comment: Not for sed: sed doesn't need, or support, escaping `"`. But your shell command uses a double-quoted string, and `\"` is correct there. The `sed` program sees `s/"text"/'text'/ig` as the argument to `-e`.

Comment: @Gilles What about spaces? Does sed understand and respect white spaces? For instance, if my command contained `s/\"text\" /'text'/ig` Would it find only `"text" ` with the space after it?

Comment: Spaces must match exactly. Rather than continue this dialogue, I recommend that you post some sample input and the corresponding desired output (and perhaps explain why you need to change the quoting). It's not even clear that `sed` is the right tool for the job, maybe you want an XML parser.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two tips:

1. You can't escape a single quote within a string quoted with single quotes. So you have to close the quote, add an escaped quote, then open the quotes again. That is: `'foo'\''bar'`, which breaks down as:

   - `'foo'`        quoted `foo`
   - `\'`             escaped `'`
   - `'bar'`        quoted `bar`

   yielding `foo'bar`.
2. (optional) You don't necessarily have to use `/` in sed. I find that using `/` and `\` in the same sed expression makes it difficult to read.

For example, to remove the quotes from this file:

```
$ cat /tmp/f
aaa"bbb"'ccc'aaa
```

Given my two tips above, the command you can use to remove both double and single quotes is:

```
$ sed -e 's|["'\'']||g'  /tmp/f
```

Based on my first tip, the shell reduces sed's second argument
(i.e., the string after the `-e`) to `s|["']||g` and passes that string to sed.
Based on my second tip, sed treats this the same as `s/['"]//g`.
It means

> remove all characters matching either `'` or `"`   (i.e., replace them with nothing)

You probably need something more complex than this to do what you want, but it's a start.

Comment: To put a finer point on your second tip: you can use any character in place of / when using the s and y commands, possibly among others. When using regexps with other sed commands, the first delimiter (if using an alternative to /) must be escaped. Your preferred delimiter must also be escaped if you are trying to match it within the regexp.

Comment: It’s hard to mix single quotes and double quotes without getting messy. Some people find it easier to read if you *quote* single quotes, by putting them in double quotes, rather than escaping them. So, rather than `'foo'\''bar'`, we might use `'foo'"'"'bar'`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Windows port of unix utilities so commands look a bit different but I had a csv file with commas and quote marks.  Using this thread as a guide, I was able to remove the quotes via this command:

```
c:\Temp> cat report.csv | sed "s/\,/\ /g" | sed "s/[""]//g"
```

Comment: thanks! was stuck on this!

Comment: Try this -- less typing:
c:\Temp> cat report.csv | sed "s/["",]//g"